# MapBoxGL with Expo installation does not work for web?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, mapbox

I am trying to build the app with the map with MapBoxGL library using Expo.
They have instructions on how to install the library which I followed as it's written here.
https://github.com/rnmapbox/maps/blob/main/plugin/install.md

After the installation, I have written the code below to present the map.

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { View } from '../components/Themed';
import { RootTabScreenProps } from '../types';
import MapboxGL from '@rnmapbox/maps';

MapboxGL.setAccessToken('PUBLIC_KEY');

export default function TabOneScreen({ navigation }: RootTabScreenProps<'TabOne'>) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapboxGL.MapView style={styles.map} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

I ran the iOS emulator with `expo start --ios`. This successfully showed the mapview. However, when I try to run the app for web with `expo start --web`, it shows the following error.

```
./node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/javascript/web/MapboxModule.js:1
Module not found: Can't resolve 'mapbox-gl'
> 1 | import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
  2 | 
  3 | const MapboxModule = {
  4 |   LineJoin: {},
./node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/javascript/web/utils/Logger.ts 2:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function */
> type LogMessage = {
|   level: LogLevel;
|   message: string;
./node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/javascript/web/components/Camera.tsx 5:36
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:36)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import MapContext from '../MapContext';
| 
> class Camera extends React.Component<{
|   centerCoordinate: [number, number] | null;
| }> {
./node_modules/@rnmapbox/maps/javascript/web/components/MapView.tsx 9:37
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:37)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  * MapView backed by Mapbox GL KS
|  */
> class MapView extends React.Component<
|   { styleURL: string; children: JSX.Element },
|   { map?: object | null }
```

It looks like a complaining linter or something but not sure how it should be solved as it's part of the library code. Is MapBoxGL web not supported at all or am I doing something wrong? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @BrianWebster no. not yet.

Answer (score 0):

`rnmapbox` has a dependency on `mapbox-gl` so if you install it with `yarn add mapbox-gl`you should be good to start. This is probably because rnmapbox uses the native map components on phones, but web doesn't have a native component so in order to render the canvas with the map in it, it uses mapbox-gl. Keep in mind (according to their docs) that it's deprecated and will be removed in a later version.

Also the reason it's probably not in the transitive dependencies is that rnmapbox first and foremost is a react-native (mobile) library and web support is experimental.